# How do I incorporate an array to speed up hiding rows?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I have a script that I want to use so that my manager can quickly see which items in the Spreadsheet need parts ordered.  The script quickly and easily hides columns containing information not pertinent to ordering parts, and then hides all rows (out of thousands) where the value in column S is FALSE (doesn't need parts ordered).  The hiding columns part is almost instant, but the hiding rows part is EXTREMELY slow.  I understand that in order to speed it up, the data should be loaded into an array, then the loop will run on the array in memory instead of making many calls to the spreadsheet.  I have seen similar questions, but the answers don't seem to explain exactly how to do this.  One example I read suggested that this is already using an array, which confused me even more.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.  Here is the script I'm using:

```
function showPartsNeeded() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange('S:S').getValues();
  for(var i=1; i< data.length; i++){
    if(data[i][0] == false){
      sheet.hideRows(i);
    }
  sheet.hideColumns(2,2);
  sheet.hideColumns(5,2);
  sheet.hideColumns(8,1);
  sheet.hideColumns(10,2);
  sheet.hideColumns(13,18);
  sheet.hideColumns(47,14);

  }
}
```

I have tried the following to load the rows that have the "Needs Parts" column marked as false into an array, then hide only the rows that are present in the array, but I only get a "Cannot find method getRange()." line 15 error and I don't understand why:

```
function showPartsNeeded() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange().getValues();
  sheet.hideColumns(2,2);
  sheet.hideColumns(5,2);
  sheet.hideColumns(8,1);
  sheet.hideColumns(10,2);
  sheet.hideColumns(13,18);
  sheet.hideColumns(47,14);
  var temp = [];
  for (var i = 1; i< data.length; i++ ) {
    if (data[i][19] == false) {
      temp.push.data[i];
    }
  }
 if (temp.length > 0 ) {
    sheet.hideRows(temp);
  }

}
```

I am fairly sure the sheet.hideRows(temp); line is wrong but I'm still trying to figure out how to use the data in the array with hideRows().

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through thousands of rows and every time you find one row with the condition you call sheet.hideRows(i). Calls to the sheet functions or ranges are very slow and that's why it is recommended to do all the operations in an array and then just insert the changes as one operation in the case of ranges.

In this case you could probably improve your code by grouping consecutive rows that follow the condition and instead of calling sheet.hideRows(i) on each of them, you could call [sheet.hideRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumncolumn)(first_row, last_row).

So if you have 10 consecutive rows that have the condition, instead of making 10 calls, you would just make one. eg. sheet.hideRows(20,30);

Comment: Hi Gerardo.  I understand your suggestions, and I see how that would work.  The only problem I have is that I also have an android app that syncs with the spreadsheet.  Rearranging rows will end up causing long sync times with this app, since every row would technically be changed and the app usually only syncs changed rows.  I have figured out how to put the data into an array I think, but I am still trying to figure out how to use that data to with hideRows().